# Extra space added to string in bash using xargs grep and can't remove it

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

I'm having a bit of trouble getting this to work properly. I've tried many different solutions thus far, but I can't seem to get the result I'm looking for. I'm still a bit of a bash newbie, but hopefully this isn't something I'm just overlooking. Here's what I'm working with:

```
cd ~/tools/bi/pdi/simple-jndi && find -name "jdbc*" | head -1 |
     xargs grep - m 1 "BILoadDS/user=" > ./test.txt
sed -i 's/ //g' test.txt

user=$(cat test.txt)

#outputs count of 26
echo ${#user}
#outputs "BILoadDS/user=john.smithy"
echo $user
```

This is where my issue arises. The literal string that is output is only 25 characters long. Why is the count I'm getting showing an extra count? For a bit more context, I'm ultimately trying to substring just the user (after the "=") as a variable for creating an ssh connection to a remote host. This has been failing thus far. I'm guessing that's because of this extra character that I can't seem to get rid of. Among the solutions I've tried are:

- various `sed` replacements
- piping the `xargs grep` to `sed`, instead of writing to file first
- using `awk` to substring what I want; it still gives output with 1 extra length

If I paste the string into Excel, `len()` returns 25 as well. I'm just not understanding why I can't get rid of this pesky extra character!

Comment: See the [bash tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) Step 1 for how to check your file or data for carriage returns

Comment: wow, i feel dumb! This was exactly my problem. Thanks very much for your help. It's always the things I spend a few hours trying to figure out that end up as an easy solution :P

Comment: When you echo a value as you showed, use something like `echo "XX${user}YY"` with distinct markers before and after the value.  When you see `YYBILoadDS/user=john.smithy` on the output, you know there's something seriously amiss, and the carriage return is the answer.  This can also help spot embedded newlines.  Also, consider outputting to a hex dump or octal dump program (`od -c`, for example).  That will show you the characters.

Answer (score 0):

<del>The extra character is the '\0' at the end of the string. This is needed because is the symbol that means end of string.</del>

If you are getting one extra character, It has to be a non printing symbol. Try run **cat** with this options that shows the non printing symbols:

- -e show nonprinting symbols and the end of the lines with $ symbol.
- -t show nonprinting symbols and TABs with ^| symbol.

More info about cat [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cat).

To get only the user:

```
sed -i 's/.*= *//' test.txt
```

This removes all characters from the beginning of the line until the last equal symbol found and the extra spaces after this symbol. Therefore, it is gotten only the user after the equal symbol.

Comment: This is incorrect. Bash string length won't include the terminating character.

Comment: Thank you Qualia. I was wrong. I changed the answer to give a better answer.